# Задание/изменение значения string константы

Tags: java, android, xml

Необходимо задать значения в `string` константу программно,  что-то типа 

`R.string.name = "Ivanov Ivan"`

Как это можно реализовать?

У меня есть лист настроек, `settings.xml` там я задаю объем воды.

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/volume_selection">

            <EditTextPreference
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_water_volume"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:key="menu_volume_max"
                android:summary="@string/max_volume_drink"
                android:title="@string/max_dose" />

            <EditTextPreference
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_water_volume"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:key="menu_volume_min"
                android:summary="@string/min_volume_drink"
                android:title="@string/min_dose" />

        </PreferenceCategory>
```

`<string name="max_volume_drink">Введите максимальный объем потребляемой воды</string>`

После того, как я внес данные, как мне написать - `Mаксимальный объем потребляемой воды Х`, где Х введенные данные.

Comment: public final static String NAME = "name" не подходит?

Answer (score 2):

Это невозможно. Значения ресурсов не изменить программно, т.к. они встраиваются в программу на этапе компиляции.

Но можно сформировать строку так, чтобы она могла принимать программно задаваемые значения и подставляла их в указанные места. Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144094/3212712):

Поместите строку в ресурсы обозначив места для подставления данных так: `%1$s` где `1` это порядковый номер аргумента для подставления в строку.

```
<string name="notyet">Website %1$s isn\'t yet available, I\'m working on it, please wait %2$s more days</string>
```

Далее в коде получайте строку методом `Context.getString(int, Object...)`

```
String site = "mywebsite";
String days = "11";

String notyet = getString(R.string.notyet, site, days);
System.out.println(notyet);
```

---

В вашем же случае правильным решением будет вешание слушателей нажатия/изменения настроек и программное назначение свойств (`summary`) `preference`. А строковые ресурсы тут использовать не нужно. Можно, но не нужно.

Comment: Вопрос отредактирован. Тут что-то возможно сделать?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександров, см. обновлённый ответ.